# How to check as to in which file is a variable declared while debugging in gdb?

Tags: c, emacs, gdb

I am going through code which is spread across multiple files. I have a variable x which i am using in file A.c and its declared in B.h. I am debugging using gdb under emacs. While in file A.c how do i check as to in which file is my variable x declared?

Comment: have you tried create tags-file with ctags/etags and tag-find-file?

Comment: no not really but ill try this.. i know that one way to do is to run grep-find under emacs but i was wondering if thr was any other way

Comment: @PeterMiehle, gdb should actually have better information than tags, since it can print for me the exact type of the variable. But somehow it doesn't provide a command for showing the location(but I'm pretty sure that it knows...)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
info variables <variable name>
```

Its a regex search, so the resultant list might be long.

UPDATE

Since its a regex search try appensing `^` at start and `$` at end to get exact match (there might be some better methods, I am no master at regex).

```
info variables ^<variable name>
```

If its too annoying try [extending GDB commands](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define) to do this.

```
(gdb)define vardef
(gdb)info variables ^$arg0$
(gdb)end
```

usage

```
(gdb) vardef <variable name>
```

You and add this extension to start up script.

P.S. In all instances of variable name above drop "<>"

Comment: that will give a long list across multiple files, all i need is to see where it is declared. Like in Visual studio, u select the variable and  click on declaration option.